# Disable css style for IE7 and IE8

Tags: css

I have style sheet file and would like to disable some css tags in it for IE7 and IE8 browsers, how to do that? I do not want to put these tabs in separated css file I would like to keep then in one file.

Comment: with "disable css tags" are you talking to hide some elements in the markup? Could you show us a specific example?

Comment: show us the css so we can provide an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend the approach taken by the HTML5 boilerplate, [outlined here by Paul Irish](http://misteroneill.com/journal/improved-internet-explorer-targeting-through-body-classes/). Basically, set up your document like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

You now have classes in place to accurately target only certain versions of IE. Your css will look like this:

```
.element { margin-bottom: 20px; }
.lt-ie8 .element { margin-bottom: 10px; }
```

You then avoid CSS hacks, and can keep everything in a single stylesheet.

As @Daniel states, this is not disabling styles, but over-riding them. If for some reason you want to send styles to *only* modern browsers and newer IE, you could add another class to the final `html` tag above, and use that.

Comment: The CSS styles overriding is that I need!

Answer (score 1):

If you try to have specific style-sheets only for IE it goes like this:

```
<!--[if IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie8.css" type="text/css" media="screen"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie7.css" type="text/css" media="screen"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen"><![endif]-->
```

More about this here: [***How To Create an IE-Only Stylesheet***](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.element {  
    margin-bottom: 20px;  
    margin-bottom: 10px\9;  
}
```

Info from here: http://www.impressivewebs.com/ie7-ie8-css-hacks/

You cannot disable them, but you can override them